# Get the real JID of user in a room

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack

I have a code to discover room occupants like this :

```
public List<String> getRoomOccupants() {

    List<String> occupants = new ArrayList<>();
    DiscoverItems discoItems = null;
    DiscoverItems.Item item = null;
    try {
        ServiceDiscoveryManager discoManager =  ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(connection);

        discoItems = discoManager.discoverItems(zipWhipNumber+"@"+roomService);

        Iterator<DiscoverItems.Item> occupantsItems = discoItems.getItems().iterator();

        while(occupantsItems.hasNext())
        {
            item = occupantsItems.next();

            occupants.add(item.getName());
            System.out.println(" EntityID : " + item.getEntityID() + "\n EntityName : " + item.getName());
        }

    } catch (NoResponseException | XMPPErrorException
            | NotConnectedException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
   return occupants;
}
```

But the EntityID is the name of the User in the room Not the full JID. So if the user by any chance changes the name to another nickname I won't be able to find his full JID.

Can anyone tell me how to get the full JID from the room ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Discovery service must to be enabled to show such infos, and depends by implementations and and MultiUserChat configuration.

Probably you are not able to get this informations with a standard *Discovery Operation*.

You can try to pass through MultiUserChat item like this:

```
RoomInfo ri = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection).getRoomInfo("zipWhipNumber+"@"+roomService");
List<String> jidUsers = ri.getContactJids());
```

or like this:

```
MultiUserChat muc = MultiUserChatManager.getInstance().getMultiUserChat("zipWhipNumber+"@"+roomService");
List<String> jidUsers = muc.getOccupants();
```

`*RoomInformation*` it's more or less  a *DiscoveryService* sized on MultiUserChat. Without right configuration, *`getContactJids()`* will return `null`.

`*getOccupants()*` of a *MultiUserChat* reply with a `List` of jids, but it's possible it sends a bad-request if user didn't previously joined the given `*MultiUserChat*`